# BGL: adjacency list returns wrong edge property for descriptor

Tags: c++, graph, boost-graph, adjacency-list

I have a graph stored as an adjacency list. The vertex property holds an int ID, and the edge property holds a 4x4 matrix and a weight;

In a test case, the graph is a 3-vertex graph with an edge connecting each pair of vertices (a complete graph).

I have a vector of edges descriptors `PathType`, representing a path, and I am iterating through it and accessing each edge and its property, `RelationshipEdge`, as follows.

```
for(PathType::iterator pathIterator = path.begin(); pathIterator != path.end(); ++pathIterator){
        edge_t edge = *pathIterator;
        RelationshipEdge rEdge = m_graph[edge];
        int sourceID = m_graph[boost::source(edge, m_graph)].id;
        int destID = m_graph[boost::target(edge, m_graph)].id;
```

However sometimes when this is performed, the  `RelationshipEdge` returned contains the data for the wrong edge.

As an example, inspecting `edge` shows an `m_source` of 1 and `m_target` of 2. If I inspect the graph and find the edge with source 1 and target 2, the weight is 3 and the matrix is as entered. However rEdge has a weight of 1, and a different matrix. Those values actually correspond with the edge with source 0 and target 1.

Am I accessing the edge properties correctly?

The definition of my graph type is:

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list< 
boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, MarkerVertex, RelationshipEdge>
CorrelationAdjacencyList;
```

Comment: Where is your graph type definition, @Joe (consider a SSCCE since your prose suggests you can reproduce the issue with a small set of data)

Comment: I've now added that. When calling other edges in the same path, and even calling the same edge in a different path, I get the correct properties returned. This is as small an example as I can create, in terms of it still testing all the functionality.

Comment: Sorry, my crystal ball is failing to think of the reason why it fails for you. Try posting a SSCCE

Answer (score 2):

I believe your error is coming from somewhere else in the code base.

I put together this simple code to test out edge access and order on a similar graph and everything works as expected.

Culprits could be manually maintained `edge_descriptors` or `vertex_descriptors` as sehe mentioned. Or perhaps your path vector initialization or construction.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>

using namespace std;

enum edge_t {A,B};

struct MarkerVertex{
    std::string id;
};

struct RelationshipEdge{
    std::string id;
};


typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS,
    MarkerVertex, RelationshipEdge> CorrelationAdjacencyList;


typedef boost::graph_traits<CorrelationAdjacencyList>::edge_descriptor   Edge;
typedef boost::graph_traits<CorrelationAdjacencyList>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;

typedef vector<Edge> PathType;


void printPath(PathType &p, CorrelationAdjacencyList &g){
    cout << "print path" << endl;

    for(PathType::iterator pi = p.begin(); pi != p.end(); ++pi){
        Edge e = *pi;

        Vertex s = boost::source(e,g);
        Vertex t = boost::target(e,g);

        cout << g[s].id << "\t" 
             << g[e].id << "\t"
             << g[t].id << endl;

        bool isFound;
        Edge eForward;
        boost::tie(eForward,isFound) = boost::edge(s,t,g);
        cout << "forward  " << g[eForward].id << "\t" << isFound << endl;

        Edge eBackward;
        boost::tie(eBackward,isFound) = boost::edge(t,s,g);
        cout << "backward " << g[eBackward].id << "\t" << isFound << endl;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    CorrelationAdjacencyList graph;

    Vertex a = boost::add_vertex(graph); graph[a].id = "a";
    Vertex b = boost::add_vertex(graph); graph[b].id = "b";
    Vertex c = boost::add_vertex(graph); graph[c].id = "c";

    Edge e1 = boost::add_edge(a,b,graph).first; graph[e1].id = "e1";
    Edge e2 = boost::add_edge(b,c,graph).first; graph[e2].id = "e2";
    Edge e3 = boost::add_edge(c,a,graph).first; graph[e3].id = "e3";

    PathType path1,path2,path3;

    path1.push_back(e1);
    path1.push_back(e2);
    path1.push_back(e3);

    path2.push_back(e2);
    path2.push_back(e3);
    path2.push_back(e1);

    path3.push_back(e3);
    path3.push_back(e2);
    path3.push_back(e1);

    printPath(path1,graph);
    cout << endl;
    printPath(path2,graph);
    cout << endl;
    printPath(path3,graph);


    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Entirely too much effort here. +1 for pure diligence

Answer (score 0):

Without further information, I can make the educated guess that you use `vecS` containers and the iterators/references have become invalidated.

This would happen on insertion/deletion of edges/vertices.

Comment: You're right on using vecS, and I have added the graph type definition into the question. I'm going through a couple of paths, and in a previous path I call the same edge but get the correct property returned. There is no insertion or deletion of edges or vertices between these iterations.

Also, in both those iterations, I have switched the source and target vertices, with no change in results. In one iteration both edges (switched and not) return the correct property but in this iteration, they both return the wrong property.

The property for the edge is still correct in the adjacency list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I found, though I'm not convinced I fully understand why the original method does not.

I have replaced the above code with

```
for(PathType::iterator pathIterator = path.begin(); pathIterator != path.end(); ++pathIterator){
    edge_t edge = *pathIterator;

    int sourceID = m_graph[boost::source(edge, m_graph)].id;
    int destID = m_graph[boost::target(edge, m_graph)].id;

    int lowerID, higherID;
    if (sourceID < destID){
        lowerID = sourceID;
        higherID = destID;
    } else {
        lowerID = destID;
        higherID = sourceID;
    }

    edge_t edge2 = m_edgeDescriptorsByEndpoints.at(make_pair(lowerID, higherID));
    RelationshipEdge rEdge = m_graph[edge2];
```

`m_edgeDescriptorsByEndpoints` is a map of pairs of vertex IDs to edge descriptors.

So I'm taking the edge descriptor, getting the IDs of the source and target vertices, finding the corresponding edge descriptor from the map and then getting the properties of that edge.

Not exactly a satisfying solution but it works, as far as I've been able to test so far.

**EDIT**

I substituted the call to my map with a call to `boost::edge(u,v,g)` as suggested by @sehe, so the code is now as follows:

```
for(PathType::iterator pathIterator = path.begin(); pathIterator != path.end(); ++pathIterator){
            edge_t edge = *pathIterator;

            vert_t sourceV = boost::source(edge, m_graph);
            vert_t targetV = boost::target(edge, m_graph);

            pair<edge_t, bool> edgePair = boost::edge(sourceV, targetV, m_graph);
            if (!edgePair.second){
                cerr << "Edge does not exist" << endl;
            }
            RelationshipEdge rEdge = m_graph[edgePair.first];
```

This code still results in rEdge containing the correct properties, which seems odd, since I'd think that querying the graph for the vertices of an edge, and then querying the graph for the edge that connects those vertices would always give you that exact same edge back.

Comment: If the order matters, it would seem like you are using a directed graph. Are you sure you are using `undirectedS`?

Comment: So edges can be traversed in any direction and in that sense it is undirected, and we are using `undirectedS`, but the property (a transformation) we store has a direction, which we need to be aware of. We've opted to always store that transformation from the point of view of the marker with the lowerID.

Comment: _"Not exactly a satisfying solution"_ I'd agree here. It doesn't sit well. I think you might have [UB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Can you share more of the code. Simple things like, what `PathType` is, and `edge_t` etc. A link to a repo will do

Comment: Also note that you can do without the map by just using [`boost::edge(u,v,g)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html):  _If an edge from vertex u to vertex v exists, return a pair containing one such edge and true. If there are no edges between u and v, return a pair with an arbitrary edge descriptor and false._ If you use `setS` for the outedge container selector, it will even be efficient. Adding an external mapping seems recipe for bugs and performance problems.

Comment: I've updated the answer, in response to this. Have a look and see what you think.

Comment: @Joe Is `PathType` just a `typedef vector<edge_t> PathType`?

Comment: Also have you thought about parallel edges? I think bgl will allow you to insert more than one edge with the same start and end unless you explicitly forbid it. You might add something like `if(!boost::edge(u,v,g).second){
    Edge e;
    bool wasAdded;
    boost::tie(e,wasAdded) = boost::add_edge(u,v,g);}` to you graph construction. See the adjacency_list [doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html) and look at the section on `edge_parallel_category`. setS disallows them by default. All others allow parallel edges by default

Comment: @pbible yes that's correct. I did consider parallel edges, but I have a very simple test case with just these three edges being added, and I have double checked there's no mistake there. There does already exist a check to see if an edge currently exists in the graph, and if I inspect the graph at the time of encountering this issue it only contains the three edges specified, with no duplicates.

Comment: Hmm, could you post the complete code of your test case that illustrates the problem?

Comment: I'm not able to do that unfortunately since it is not my IP to share, and to show the whole test case as it is would require showing a lot of code that surrounds these parts.